# What is the difference between using execle and, putenv followed by an execl?

Tags: c, linux, unix

Say I `putenv` an environment variable ABC and then do an `execl`, or I do an `execle` and add ABC to the envp array of pointers that I pass to `execle`.

Is there a difference, if any?

Comment: @sturcotte06 Can you explain your comment, please?

Comment: Assuming the envp you pass to `execle` is otherwise identical to the current environment, there is no difference. (Unless `execle` fails, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putenv` adds an environment variable to the current environment. Using `execl` will then use that environment.

`execle` will use the environment argument as the entire environment, i.e. it won't inherit the existing environment variables.

It's easy to see this with a simple program that just runs `env` (which prints out the current environment):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    execl("/bin/env", "/bin/env", NULL);
}
```

Running this on my machines prints out a lot of environment variables such as `HOME`, etc.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char* env[] = { NULL };
    execle("/bin/env", "/bin/env", NULL, env);
}
```

This prints nothing, because the environment is empty.